# How to manage multiple local methods in java rmi coding

Tags: java, parallel-processing, rmi

When I do RMI coding i follow the following steps

1. First creating an remote interface.
2. Then implement the interface in a remote class.
3. Then implement a server class program.
4. Then implement a client class program.
5. then compile and run

Now I am trying to do:

1. First creating an remote interface.
2. Then implement the interface in multiple remote class.
3. Then implement a server class program.
4. Then implement a client class program.

I have done first two steps but don't know how to do step 3 and step 4 because i don't know how to manage multiple remote classes.

My code is below:

1. Interface

Calculator.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Calculator extends Remote
{    
    public int sum(int x,int y) throws RemoteException;
}
```

2. local classes

Addition.java

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;



public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator 
{

    public Addition() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();

    }


    public int sum(int x,int y) throws RemoteException
    {
        return x+y;
    }


}
```

Subtraction.java

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class Subtraction extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator
{




    public Subtraction() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();


    }

    public int sum(int x,int y) throws RemoteException
    {
        return x-y;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to implement a server class for multiple local classes. But I have no idea, **how to communicate** with those multiple local classes using server, that's why I am stuck.

So, I need little help with that.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. NB Why all the bold-face? I hope you don't think it helps. It doesn't. Try tio taper off.

Comment: okay, i am trying to say, i have a interface, i can implement in single class. but now i implement it on multiple classes. now i want to manage them using server and client. but i don't know how to manage them using server and client

Comment: Define 'manage'. Question remains incomprehensible. Try harder. Imagine you're trying to explain to your grandmother.

Comment: in here 'manage' means communicate between different multiple remote class and server and client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your interface code: you have misspelled the name of the interface itself.
2. Notice the name of remote method sum, I have changed it to 'calculate' in my answer, to make it more relevant. (You have used the method 'sum' to do both addition and subtraction)
3. You have created multiple implementations of your interface. It is unclear, what you 'want to do' with them next.
4. Assuming you want to create a server-client model where you have multiple implementations of one interface and you want to invoke any of them, you can set up a server for each of your implementations:

> Interface (Filename: Calculator.java)

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Calculator extends Remote{
    //remote method declaration    
    public int calculate(int x,int y) throws RemoteException;
}
```

> Implementation 1 of interface: Calculator (Filename: Addition.java)

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator{

    public Addition() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    public int calculate(int x,int y) throws RemoteException{
        //define what your remote method will do
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

> Implementation 2 of interface: Calculator (Filename: Subtraction.java)

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Subtraction extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator{

    public Subtraction() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    public int calculate(int x,int y) throws RemoteException{
        return x-y;
    }
}
```

> Server code for Addition class (Filename: ADDserver.java)

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ADDserver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            //take input the port number
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String portname, registryURL; 
            System.out.println("Enter port:");
            String portNum = (br.readLine()).trim();
            //create remote object
            Addition exportedObj = new Addition();
            //generate registry url for rmi registry server
            registryURL = "rmi://localhost:" + portNum + "/Add";
            //assosiate your object with the url in rmiregistry 
            Naming.rebind(registryURL, exportedObj);
            System.out.println("ADDserver ready");
        } catch (Exception re){
            System.out.println("Exception in ADDserver: " + re);
        }
    }
}
```

> Server code for Subtraction class (Filename: SUBserver.java)

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SUBserver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String portname, registryURL; 
            System.out.println("Enter port:");
            String portNum = (br.readLine()).trim();
            Subtraction exportedObj = new Subtraction();
            registryURL = "rmi://localhost:" + portNum + "/Subtract";
            Naming.rebind(registryURL, exportedObj);
            System.out.println("SUBserver ready");
        } catch (Exception re){
            System.out.println("Exception in SUBserver: " + re);
        }
    }
}
```